# VB.NET extracting text inbetween HTML characters

Tags: regex, vb.net

So I'm creating an application which will give you stats on you spotify account etc, after successfully logging in I'm trying to determin your Subscription status from the https://spotify.com/account/subscription/ page.

```
Dim Info As Match = Regex.Match(html, "<h3 class=""product-name"">(\d+)</h3>")
Label3.Text = "Account Type: " + Info.Groups(1).Value
```

When writing the outcome of `Info.Groups(1).Value` to the console I get a blank, Any Ideas on how to get the value between the `<h3></h3>`'s?

Comment: Don't use Regex for parsing HTML. Instead, use an HTML parser like [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/).

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed no need to go that far for simple use. Regex work just fine in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the value between the `<h3></h3>`

```
Dim Info As Match = Regex.Match(html, "<h3.*>(.*)<\/h3>")
Label3.Text = "Account Type: " + Info.Groups(1).Value
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm!